# SAX Parsing with special characters in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

I am trying to parse xml file which contains some special character `if (($a &gt; 7))` I am using StringBuffer to read these characters but its not reading the whole string. All the characters after `&gt;` has been chopped off. All its returning me is `if(($a`. Please suggest me.
Thanks

Comment: please show your tried code to get help

Comment: Yes proper way to escape Entities References like >,< and other reserved key word is to use CDATA but i am trying to read xml file of third party so there is no point of me adding CDATA to the file. I have to solve the issue without the use of CDATA. Any suggestion. And i have to use SAX not DOM because of memory issue. Working fine with DOm parser but I am getting memory issue so I thought of using SAX.

Answer (score 3):

When you parse XML with SAX, you can get the text of an element in *multiple* method calls.  you *must* accumulate the text across all the calls until you get the `endElement` call.

Comment: +1 This is a pitfall commonly overlooked.  The parser is free to give you text in as many pieces as it wants to, which you must concatenate.